Where to use Date.now function for saving data to database
I have a REST API server with Express, connects to MongoDB. Basically my app accept an input form to save some reports daily and of course the timestamp has to be that current time.
My question is, should I use Date.now() when creating the Request body (in the client-side) or should I use it on my server controller (server-side)?
In the second option, I could use the { default : Date.now() } on the model schema or inside model constructor in controller file.
Regardless what option I go with, the difference of the timestamp depends on how long it took to process the request. The body consists bit of data, mostly strings and number and does not exceed 100kb.
I'm curious how is people approach to this kind of problem

do you even trust the client's clock to be set correctly? is the time for your benefit or the clients? if the client's, use that, otherwise use an authoritative time.

If it's a technical date to store the exact moment of record creation then it should be on DB side only (like for instance usually done by using two fields to store the creation and last update timestamps)
